# How do I get this redstone to be lighted through two blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to hide this redstone trail with a plank but i need it to still be powered by a button, therefore I'd need the redstone signal to 'go through' two blocks. Is there any way to do this?
I tried using a redstone torch underneath the plank but it didn't seem to cooperate with buttons.

[image: Picture of redstone trail working as it should going through one block]

[image: How I'm trying to get the trail to look (hidden).]

Comment: Also I can't move the trail AROUND as it breaks into the walls. I need the button in this exact pos. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks :)

Comment: There might be a way to exploit https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-108, but you would have to have a clock around there that constantly gives block updates to the piston/dispenser/dropper.

Comment: You could move the button 1 block lower.

Comment: @FabianRöling it would also make a noise because of the constantly ticking piston/dispenser/dropper

Comment: Droppers that put items into another container make no noise. And block updates can also be silent. But stuffing all of that in the small available area would be quite challenging and I'm not too invested in bugusing-based solutions anyway, so I won't design a circuit.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of any way to make this happen except for replacing a wood log with an observer and putting the button on that. All you need to do then is make sure the redstone in the back is connected. Tell me if it helps, but that's the only way I can think of. Sorry!